# JAVA RESTFull server get POST data with "%" (percentege) as value @FormParam

Tags: java, rest, post, parameters, jersey

I`m making and **REST client** that recive a **POST** with data to use as **filter** on a query.
My problem is when the client send me a **"%"** to search for all the values.

Jersey send me the following error

```
11:36:35,857 ERROR [Jersey REST Service]:260 - Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "%ip%"
```

The code who is generating this error is:

```
@POST
    @Path("/Comercial/{campo}")
    @Produces("application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public static Response findAll(
                @PathParam(value = "campo") String campo,
                @FormParam("filtro") String filtro){

        Object resposta = null;

        resposta = new JSONArray();
        campo = campo.substring(7);
        resposta = SequenciaControl.findDataByTable(campo,filtro);

        return Retorno.send(resposta);
    }
```

this works if i recive as a GET using @QueryParam, but i need this as a POST

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentage has to be escaped using `%25` while sending it as a request.

So, `"%ip%"` should be `"%25ip%25"`